# How to override CSS class from css.scss file on spree_fancy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, spree

I want to override some CSS files from spree_fancy:

```
https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy
```

When I find for the file I want to override, I discover that it is an SCSS file (SASS). This is the file I´m taking about:

```
https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/2-1-stable/app/assets/stylesheets/store/components/_product_item.scss
```

I suppose, after some readings, that I need to write this file on my local app and add there the class I want to override, like this:

```
https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/2-1-stable/app/assets/stylesheets/store/variables_override.css.scss

#product-thumbnails {
....
}
```

When I reload the send request to server again, the changes are not applied. I tried also restarting the web server, but still no results.

Can someone please tell me if I´m missing something here in order to get it work?

*Added contents of my variables_override.css.scss file:

```
#product-thumbnails {
  margin-right: -20px;

  li {
    border: none;
    margin-right: 12px;

    a {
      border: 1px solid lighten($body_text_color, 30);
      text-align: center;
      display: block;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      @include opacity(0.7);

      &:hover {
        @include opacity(1);
        border-color: $c_green;
      }

      &, img {
        @include border-radius(300px);
      }

      img {
        padding: 0px;
      }
    }

    &.selected a {
      @include opacity(1);
      border-color: $c_green;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you add your html code as well? Also, are all these style sheets in your asset pipeline?

Comment: There is no specific HTML code written by me. What I try to do is to use something already done with some modifications (design). So all the HTML code is on `https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy` and `https://github.com/spree/spree`, under the app/views folders.
In regarding to asset pipeline, I´m afraid I don´t know what this is. Do you mean this? `https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/fancy.scss`

Comment: Ok, so how are you using these style sheets? Are you using the spree-fancy gem, if so then they are automatically inserted into your asset pipeline. This leads to 'variables_override' style sheet in app/assets/stylesheets folder. There you can add your overriding style code.

Comment: Yes, spree-fancy is a gem bundled on my app. And this is exactly what I´m doing. But it seems I´m missing something because I can´t see any results. The exact path on my app is ´app/assets/stylesheets/store/variables_override.css.scss´. Do I need to do something else? Like some compilation of the scss file? I´m running in development mode on local.

Comment: I am confused, I checked out the views code on spree git repo but I cannot find 'product-thumbnails' id anywhere in the erb files. Could you write the whole code of 'variables_override.css.scss'?

Comment: Ok, I added an example of what I want to do. I want to change the padding and the border-radius properties in order to show the image fitting with the circular border. But it doesn´t matter the change itself, I would like to change whatever and I´m not able to do so. The point here is: Do I need to do something else? or just writing a class on file variables_override.css.scss and refresh web explorer? Perhaps I´m pointing to the incorrect class as you suggest...

Comment: Your local file will need to match the full name and path of the file you want to override.  It should be at app/assets/stylesheets/store/variables_override.css.scss